# App Store allows only iOS 10 or newer when deployment target is set to iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, app-store, ios9, xcode9, deployment-target

I have set deployment target to iOS 8.0 in both project and target settings (Xcode 9.2, Swift 4). Everything builds fine and with my testing iPhone 4S device (iOS 9.3.5) I can run app and works fine.
[image: Deployment Target in Xcode]

My problem is that same build in App Store allows only to download app for iOS 10 or newer. I get this message when trying to download from App Store:

> "App name" is not compatible with this iPhone.

When I tried to look for way to fix this I found this in iTunes Connect (it's in Pricing and Availability section):
[image: last-compatible versions for iOS app]

Why there is no older version? How can I fix this? I probably dont need to support iOS 8 but I want to support iOS 9.

Thanks for all help

Comment: @thorb65 can you pls share the apple documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things worth doing:

1. In Build Settings->Architecture, ensure that Build Active Architecture Only is set to NO, particularly for the Release section.
2. When archiving the project for distribution, ensure that the device at the top left corner of XCode is set to "Generic iOS Device" and not a device connected to your MacBook via USB. This is because despite setting Build Active Architecture to NO, XCode seems to not honour the setting.
   Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67488

Comment: I have NO for Build Active Architecture Only but I probably archived project with connected device via USB. So I'll try with "Generic iOS Device" and see if it helps.

Comment: For TestFlight it works (I can download it now to iPhone 4S and I couldnt before) so it looks like second point helps but I want to sent it to App Store to be sure.